# Sharing dlls between two projects in .net

Tags: c#, .net

how to deploy reference dlls if i kept setting CopyLocal = False at the time of development?

As reference dlls will be in some different location at deployment server?

Answer (score 3):

You can share your `assemblies` by installing them into [Global Assemble Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: These assamblies are project related and not global and some of them are not our own dlls so it is not signed and i dont want to keep our project dlls to GAC as production server is also used by other teams....

Answer (score 2):

You can manually copy them to the bin directory when you deploy it.

Comment: i dont want to do that as i have so multiple projects deploy there and i want to share these common dlls between those projects.

Comment: another option could be to use a system variable, e.g. %DLLPATH% in the location for your dlls then you would add this path to the various machines defining the different location.

Answer (score 2):

You can have dlls located on a share somewhere `(e.g. /bin/SubDir)`, set `CopyLocal` to `false` and make sure your project's references path (in Properties) includes the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the Copy Local to false then try adding the reference to that DLL using add reference in VS.

Go To `Soloution Explorer -> Right Click ->  Add Reference ->Browse ->Select the DLL`

The other approach will be , installing your DLL to GAC by using GACUtil.exe:
   **`gacutil -i [assemblyPath ]`**

Comment: if you read comments below i dont want to use GAC. My problem is at the deployment not at development